# How to find transformation between two rotation matrices

Tags: transformation, rotations

The problem I'm trying to solve is following: I have two rotation matrices in 3d space, each from a different coordinate frame - one is a rotation matrix A with zero rotation in all directions, the second matrix B has some rotations in all directions. I want to find a transformation between these two rotation matrices, so that when I get more matrices like B, I will be able to use this transformation to transform it to the coordinate frame of the matrix A.

How can I get this transformation? Is it enough to know just one point in each coordinate frame?

Comment: So A is the identity?

Comment: Do you want express B in the coordinates frame of A?

Comment: @gimusi I don't know if it's the identity, I have limited knowledge in this area. But if I express it in euler angles, all of them are zero in case of A. And yes, I want to express B in coordinates frame of A.

Comment: Are you aware about change of  basis?

Comment: Therefore we know the coordinate frames for A and B with respect to the standard frame?